# creation of unit tests with users

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing

I want to test the next method of my controller

```
function index(){
        if(Auth::User()->can('view_roles'))
        {
            $roles = Role::all();
            return response()->json(['data' => $roles], 200);
        }

        return response()->json(['Not_authorized'], 401);
    }
```

it is already configured for authentication (tymondesigns / jwt-auth) and the management of roles (spatie / laravel-permission), testing with postman works, I just want to do it in an automated way.

This is the test code, if I remove the conditional function of the controller the TEST passes, but I would like to do a test using a user but I have no idea how to do it.

```
public function testIndexRole()
{
    $this->json('GET', '/role')->seeJson([
        'name' => 'admin',
        'name' => 'secratary'
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Depends on what kind of app are you building.

## A - Using Laravel for the entire app

If your using Laravel for frontend/backend, well to simulate a logged-in user you could use the awesome [Laravel Dusk](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/dusk) package, made by the Laravel team. You can check the [documentation here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/dusk#installation).

This package has some helpful methods to mock login sessions amongs a lot more of other things, you can use:

```
$this->browse(function ($first, $second) {
    $first->loginAs(User::find(1))
          ->visit('/home');
});
```

That way you hit an endpoint with a logged-in user of `id=1`. And a lot more of stuff.

---

---

## B - Using Laravel as a backend

Now, this is mainly how I use Laravel.

To identify a user that hits an endpoint, the request must send an `access_token`. This token helps your app to identify the user. So, you will need to make and API call to that endpoint attaching the token.

I made a couple of helper functions to simply reuse this in every Test class. I wrote a `Utils` trait that is being used in the `TestCase.php` and given this class is extended by the rest of the Test classes it will be available everywhere.

### 1. Create the helper methods.

path/to/your/project/ tests/Utils.php

```
Trait Utils {

/**
     * Make an API call as a User
     *
     * @param $user
     * @param $method
     * @param $uri
     * @param array $data
     * @param array $headers
     * @return TestResponse
     */
    protected function apiAs($user, $method, $uri, array $data = [], array $headers = []): TestResponse
    {
        $headers = array_merge([
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . \JWTAuth::fromUser($user),
            'Accept'        => 'application/json'
        ], $headers);

        return $this->api($method, $uri, $data, $headers);
    }


    protected function api($method, $uri, array $data = [], array $headers = [])
    {
        return $this->json($method, $uri, $data, $headers);
    }
}
```

### 2. Make them available.

Then in your `TestCase.php` use the trait:

path/to/your/project/tests/TestCase.php

```
abstract class TestCase extends BaseTestCase
{
    use CreatesApplication, Utils; // <-- note `Utils`

    // the rest of the code
```

### 3. Use them.

So now you can do API calls from your test methods:

```
/** 
* @test
* Test for: Role index
*/
public function a_test_for_role_index()
{
    /** Given a registered user */
    $user = factory(User::class)->create(['name' => 'John Doe']);

    /** When the user  makes the request */
    $response = $this->apiAs($user,'GET', '/role');

    /** Then he should see the data */
    $response
        ->assertStatus(200)
        ->assertJsonFragment(['name' => 'admin'])
        ->assertJsonFragment(['name' => 'secretary']);
}
```

---

---

## Side note

check that on top of the test methods there is a `@test` annotation, this indicates Laravel that the method is a test. You can do this or prefix your tests names with `test_`